# Matrix and Node Padding

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to gain a little vertical padding with a `matrix of nodes` and having trouble. In a regular `matrix` I could just add `[2em]` etc after the row or column delimiter to add a little padding between rows or columns. That's not seeming to work in a `matrix of nodes`. Suggestions??

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning,matrix}

\tikzset{
    state/.style={rounded rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=3em ,minimum width = 6em, inner sep = 5pt},
    test/.style = {diamond, draw, shape aspect=2, inner sep = 0pt,text width = 7em,text centered},
    action/.style ={rectangle, draw,text width=8em,inner sep = 3pt, minimum height=5em},
    data/.style = {trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120pt, minimum height = 6em},
    line/.style = {draw, -triangle 45},
    list/.style = {rectangle, draw,minimum width = 6em},
    ptr-box/.style = {rectangle, text width = 8em}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    align = flush center,
    font = \small]
    \matrix [
        matrix of nodes,
        column sep = 0.5em,
        row sep = 1.3em, 
        draw, dashed,
        nodes = {solid},
        ] (mtrx)
    {  
    |[state]| \\
    |[data]|  b\\
    |[test]|  c\\
    |[action]|d\\
    |[test]|  e\\
    |[action]|f\\
    |[action]|g\\[2em] %Not working
    }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I should have been more specific. I'm looking to add space only at the bottom and possibly to one side of the `matrix of nodes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to add another empty row. If you want to have `2em` in sum you'd add `[.7em]` to your last `\\` as it will add another `row sep`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning,matrix}
\tikzset{
    state/.style={rounded rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=3em ,minimum width = 6em, inner sep = 5pt},
    test/.style = {diamond, draw, shape aspect=2, inner sep = 0pt,text width = 7em,text centered},
    action/.style ={rectangle, draw,text width=8em,inner sep = 3pt, minimum height=5em},
    data/.style = {trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120pt, minimum height = 6em},
    line/.style = {draw, -triangle 45},
    list/.style = {rectangle, draw,minimum width = 6em},
    ptr-box/.style = {rectangle, text width = 8em}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    align = flush center,
    font = \small]
    \matrix [
        matrix of nodes,
        column sep = 0.5em,
        row sep = 1.3em, 
        draw, dashed,
        nodes = {solid},
        ] (mtrx)
    {  
    |[state]| \\
    |[data]|  b\\
    |[test]|  c\\
    |[action]|d\\
    |[test]|  e\\
    |[action]|f\\
    |[action]|g\\[.7em]
    \\
   }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm looking to add space only at the bottom and possibly to one side of the `matrix of nodes` The `inner *sep` is very close, but still adds to both ends.

Comment: @blitzvergnugen If you add one more `\\` after your last row you get an extra empty row (and the `2em` get into account). You can then adjust it to your needs (but the empty row has its own height).

Comment: @blitzvergnugen I've updated my answer. Does this achieve what you wanted (looks odd to me, though)?

Comment: That works. I have a path that comes out of `g.south` and snakes up, so that's why I wanted the space at just the bottom. Seems like a deficiency of `matrix of nodes` to not have the same fine grained control of spacing like a regular `matrix` though.

Comment: @blitzvergnugen Why not use `\path (g.south) ++(0,-2em) …` or the like?

Comment: I'm trying to keep the path inside the border of the matrix.